# Icons not visible on Xamarin.UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm creating Xamarin.Forms application. I'm facing some [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGoDg.png) of icons who are not visible on Xamarin.UWP. I've shared my code block which contains icons.
If anyone has any idea regarding this then please let me know. Thanks.

```
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Neuigkeiten" Icon="Neuigkeiten.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:TestPage/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Mitarbeiter" Icon="Mitarbeiter.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:TestPage/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Zusammenarbeit" Icon="Zusammenarbeit.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:TestPage/>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
```

Comment: Do you see an Image if you use an Image control directly instead of the Navigationpage, e.g. a ContentPage containing <Image Source="Neuigkeiten.png" />

Comment: Yes @MouseOnMars I can see Image only the problem is with icons.

Comment: @HeliShah Where did you place these images? Could you please share a sample to help me reproduce this issue on my side?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT As this is my testing application, So I have placed images in my uwp solution folder itself.

Comment: @HeliShah Hi, Did it work for you?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT below solution works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `TabbedPage.HeaderIconsEnabled` attached property to true on UWP to display the icon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/windows/tabbedpage-icons

Here is the code sample:

```
<TabbedPage ...
            xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            windows:TabbedPage.HeaderIconsEnabled="true">
    <windows:TabbedPage.HeaderIconsSize>
        <Size>
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:Double>24</x:Double>
                <x:Double>24</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
        </Size>
    </windows:TabbedPage.HeaderIconsSize>
    <NavigationPage Title="Neuigkeiten" Icon="Neuigkeiten.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:TestPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
        ...
</TabbedPage>
```